# Diffrences between cdev_add and device_create function?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am newbie on linux device driver development. I can't understand what cdev_add actually do.I viewed some simple char device driver code and I saw, cdev_add and device_create function used together. 
For instance:

```
/* Create device class, visible in /sys/class */
dummy_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "dummy_char_class");
if (IS_ERR(dummy_class)) {
    pr_err("Error creating dummy char class.\n");
    unregister_chrdev_region(MKDEV(major, 0), 1);
    return PTR_ERR(dummy_class);
}

/* Initialize the char device and tie a file_operations to it */
cdev_init(&dummy_cdev, &dummy_fops);
dummy_cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;
/* Now make the device live for the users to access */
cdev_add(&dummy_cdev, devt, 1);

dummy_device = device_create(dummy_class,
                            NULL,   /* no parent device */
                            devt,    /* associated dev_t */
                            NULL,   /* no additional data */
                            "dummy_char");  /* device name */
```

What cdev_add and device_create do in this code?

Comment: cdev from older linux kernel architecture, and new versions need dev_create. but dev_create still depends on cdev.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use a character driver, first you should register it with the system. Then you should expose it to the user space.

`cdev_init` and `cdev_add` functions perform the character device registration. 
[cdev_add](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.8/source/fs/char_dev.c#L472) adds the character device to the system. When `cdev_add` function successfully completes, the device is live and the kernel can invoke its operations.

In order to access this device from user space, you should create a device node in `/dev`. You do this by creating a virtual device class using [class_create](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4/source/include/linux/device.h#L517), then creating a device and registering it with `sysfs` using the [device_create](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.9/source/drivers/base/core.c#L1607) function. `device_create` will create a device file in `/dev`.

Read [Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/), chapter 3 (Char Drivers) for a good description of the process (`class_create` and `device_create` are not covered in the book).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have one more question. Do I have to use cdev_init  and cdev_add, if i use sysfs attributes instead open, write ,read, ioctl etc?

Comment: @overlord No, then you don't have to register a character device.